# SQLite command line: How do you pipe output to a UNIX utility?

Tags: pipe, sqlite

The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#section_5)  for its command line client indicates that its possible to filter output of SQLite queries through UNIX utilities:

> The default output mode is "list".
>   [...]
>   List mode is especially useful when
>   you are going to send the output of a query to another program (such
>   as AWK) for additional processing.

example of output produced at an SQLite command prompt

```
sqlite> select * from todos;
1|finish reading getting started section of the vim manual
2|finish app feature
```

then, if I try adding a pipe to the command, I just get a new prompt

```
sqlite> select * from todos; | grep vim
...>
```

Is it possible to send output to a unix utility using a pipe from the SQLite command line, or is it only possible to filter SQLite output if you are actually writing a C application and using the SQLite C library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pipe output from an interactive SQLite session because it's not a shell.  `|` doesn't do in SQL what it does on a command line.  What you probably need to do is something akin to `sqlite3 /path/to/mydata.sqlite "select * from todos" | grep vim`, which will execute the SQL, and `grep` the output as you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to filter the output of a query through a command by prefacing the argument to `.output` or `.once` with a `|`.

```
.once '|grep vim'
select * from todos;
```

Unfortunately, this does not interact well with programs that take over your whole terminal, like pagers.  For that, I highly recommend [litecli](https://litecli.com/).

https://sqlite.org/cli.html#writing_results_to_a_file